# how to disable the fiddler capturing my web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, security, fiddler

i don't want to fiddler capturing my web application activity . i want to make my application more secure like banking site .while using internet banking site the fiddler cannot able to capturing the details. how can i make it by using C#.net in asp.net web application.

Comment: I think you've not tried hard enough to intercept the traffic to your bank's server: Fiddler runs as a proxy and that's a core part of HTTP.

Answer (score 2):

Fiddler can also capture HTTPS traffic if the user accepts the root authority certificate it installs when you enable '[Decrypt HTTPS traffic](http://www.fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp)' in Fiddler Options.

Fiddler acts as a standard HTTP proxy. There is no way you can prevent Fiddler from intercepting and decrypting the traffic if the user chooses so, although [Certificate Pinning](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/CertPinning) can make things a bit harder on the Fiddler user.

You could of course use some kind of symmetric encryption to encrypt the payload of your requests, but you'd need to store the key somewhere on the client, making it vulnerable to attackers. See [here](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) for more info on JavaScript encryption.

Answer (score 0):

```
Request.Proxy = New WebProxy()
```

This blocks the fiddler to set itself as a proxy.